# System.Data.SQLite and strange File.Copy errors

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I find that File.Copy will gladly copy a file onto itself without throwing an exception. By mistake I copied a sqlite database file onto itself, and the file is no longer a valid database. 
I have repeated this as a test several times and get the same result. Using winmerge (or a text editor) I see that the result file has 0 bytes, but windows explorer still shows the original file size.
What have I missed here?
(vs2008, win7-64)

Edit: some code. Pretty simplistic I know. And it's not 0 bytes, it's all nuls.

```
        public bool RestoreDatabaseSqlite(string backupFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(backupFilePath, _databaseFilePath, true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error restoring database file: " + ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Edit #2: The problem is specific to System.Data.SQLite, an open SQLiteConnection on the file, and the interaction with File.Copy. I would expect the file copy to fail with an exception, but it just silently nuls out the entire file.

Comment: Did you check with a binary safe editor(for example a hex editor) or only simple text editors?

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong. Just tried it myself with File.Copy method and you get "The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process". Please post your code, as it's *not* using File.Copy

Comment: Using wnbrowse it looks like it's all nuls.

Comment: Are you totally sure backupFilePath and _databaseFilePath are the same? If so can you somehow attach them so we can reproduce?

Comment: Hmm.. try to Stop the database before you execute this code. The fact it's active and "listening" to the file might explain such odd behavior.

Comment: It appears that if a SQLiteConnection (System.Data.SQLite) is open on the file, the file copy doesn't throw an exception and the file is munged. Very strange.

Comment: So can't you just make sure the connection is closed and get it solved?

Answer (score 3):

Quick test:

```
File.Copy("foo.htm", "foo.htm");
```

throws an `IOException`:

> The file 'foo.htm' already exists.

Trying with overwrite:

```
File.Copy("foo.htm", "foo.htm", true);
```

throws an `IOException`:

> The process cannot access the file 'foo.htm' because it is being used by another process.

So generally it looks to be covered. Are you doing something *specific*?

---

I added some additional double-checking, and it still seems fine:

```
Console.WriteLine("Before:");
Console.Write(File.ReadAllText("foo.htm"));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("After:");
try
{
    File.Copy("foo.htm", "foo.htm", true);
}
catch (IOException) {
    Console.Write(File.ReadAllText("foo.htm"));
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with your reply and this is what I would expect. The file is destroyed however, replaced with all nuls. I added the code to my question. I'll keep trying to find what my screwup is.. My customer found this bug today, and I reproduced it.

Comment: I just stepped through the code in the debugger, verified the file paths are identical, and it didn't throw an exception, and the file is munged. I wrote a short console app as a reality check to test File.Copy and it does throw the exception as you say.

Comment: If I do the same test as in my previous comment, but put the File.Copy within the context of an open sqlite connection on the file (which is something I know is wrong), I can reproduce this bug.

Comment: Yes and it only seems to mung the file if the source file is the same as the destination. If source != destination then it seems to copy okay.